# RPI sometimes freezes on reboot , what to do?

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, reboot

I have an RPI 0 W which I use a script on to run 24/7 ,

Sometimes the script fails and a system reboot is required which I do by the command `sudo reboot`,
Sometimes while rebooting the RPI is getting frozen on the booting screen and the only way for me to fix that is to re-plug the power supply of the RPI...

I use a good SD card (evo plus samsung 32gb) and my GUI is disabled so I did everything possible to make the RPI run as smoothly as possible , what can I do to prevent this issue competently?

Example of the RPI display when its frozen: 
http://prntscr.com/pc615v but cron.service not always shown (its pretty much random on what its getting stuck)

Comment: *"frozen on the booting screen"* -> Is this a view of text output or something graphical?

Comment: @goldilocks its grafical , for example : http://prntscr.com/pc615v but cron.service not always shown (its pretty much random on what its getting stuck)

Comment: Does your application require read/write on the SD card? Switching to a read-only root filesystem might improve reliability, e.g. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=161416

Comment: What does the script do? Heavy network access? Heavy disk access? Or both? Or what?

Comment: @Ingo , its a proxy server so I guess it does heavy network access , I don't know about the disk access

Comment: A proxy server running as script? Seems to be very unlikely. Do you mean a script that starts a proxy server? What script is it? What proxy server?

Comment: @Ingo There is a 4g dongle connected to the rpi , abd the rpi is working as a 4g proxy